# How do I transform an union type of string literal types into a inlined version in mapped types?

Tags: typescript

Say I have the input:

```js
type UnionType = 'cat' | 'dog' | 'bird';
type MappedType = {
  [Key in UnionType]: UnionType;
};
```

But this only gives:

```js
type MappedType = {
  'cat': UnionType;
  'dog': UnionType;
  'bird': UnionType;
}
```

What I want to achieve is:

```js
type MappedType = {
  'cat': 'cat' | 'dog' | 'bird';
  'dog': 'cat' | 'dog' | 'bird';
  'bird': 'cat' | 'dog' | 'bird';
}
```

That is, without revealing the type name `UnionType`. Is this possible?

Comment: What does "without revealing the type name `UnionType`" mean? Your desired type is `Record<UnionType, UnionType>`. Are you asking about how the compiler chooses to *display* the type via IntelliSense or something? If so then maybe `{[K in UnionType]: UnionType & {}}`?  Note that `Cat` is a very strange name for a generic type parameter and I suggest you change it to something more conventional like `K`. Could you [edit] to clarify the above?

Comment: @jcalz Your comment resolves my question! Thank you!

Comment: I don't understand the first part with `type MappedType = { [Key in UnionType]: Key; }`; surely that would never work or do what you're trying to do.  Maybe you could [edit] to *start* with `{[Key in UnionType]: UnionType}` and then focus the question on how the type is *displayed* (because there's nothing "wrong" with `Record<UnionType, UnionType>`, you're just concerned about whether quickinfo is inlined for some reason).  Could you make that edit and I'll write an answer or find a suitable dupe target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type you have is equivalent to the type you want. You are concerned primarily with how the type is *displayed*, but there's no sure-fire documented way for developers to control this. It's essentially the prerogative of the compiler to choose how such things are displayed, and it uses heuristics to determine when to leave named types as-is and when to replace the names with their definitions. There's a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#45954](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/45954) to give developers some more control, and there's also [microsoft/TypeScript#28508](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/28508) to allow for "expandable" definitions. But for now, this is somewhat out of our hands.

Of course there are ways to take advantage of the compiler's heuristic rules to try to change the displayed type.  One thing you can do here is to [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) `UnionType` with `{}`, the empty type.  The empty type matches anything except `null` and `undefined`, so `UnionType & {}` is completely equivalent to `UnionType`.  But TypeScript doesn't want to display `UnionType & {}` as-is; it tries to evaluate it further:

```
type MappedType = { [K in UnionType]: UnionType & {} };
/* type MappedType = {
    cat: "cat" | "dog" | "bird";
    dog: "cat" | "dog" | "bird";
    bird: "cat" | "dog" | "bird";
} */
```

So that gives you the behavior you want. For this particular use case, for TypeScript 5.4.  But again, there is no guarantee here. Perhaps some future version of TypeScript will change the way this is displayed. It might be worthwhile to try to understand *why* you care about which of two equivalent types is displayed, and whether there's some other approach (e.g., more documentation of your code) which wouldn't depend on it.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCrmgXigcgMYCGwOUAPrgCZIDmJ5OARggE4U4DcAUJ6JFALIEwkCuj7YA3lADaAaSgI4sRCjEQAugC5lyNBigAyKBIC+UE1wD0AKii9og4RFH7JnKB6iFg2gETffMihfKmpA8l8mVl8uTyhQvwCgkJpw4KiKGPdPDMSiNJSw5Iyss2tLIA)